# Exception mapper isn't being called

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

Here is my exception mapper

```
@Provider
class JsonParseExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<JsonParseException> {
@Override
public Response toResponse(final JsonParseException  jpe) {       
    return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST)
            .entity("Invalid data supplied for request").build();
}
}
```

but I'm not able to capture the parser error. I'm using Jersey 1.16

My Service

```
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response createUsers(ArrayList<User> users) {....
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your exception mapper is not added to a set of classes of the Application instance.

Comment: I can see in console window under INFO: Provider classes found: JsonParseExceptionMapper